# The property near infinity of a complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, singularity

Given a meromorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{S}^2$ satisfies
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{|f'(z)|^2}{(1+|f(z)|^2)^2}dxdy<+\infty,$$
prove that $f$ is a rational function.

My attempts:

It suffices to check that $\infty$ is not an essential singularity of $f$. Otherwise, it will cover the extended complex plane infinitely many times (possibly except for one point). How to go on and use the integrable condition? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that the integrand should be $\frac{|f'(z)|^2}{(1+|f(z)|^2)^2}$, i.e. the square of the spherical derivative?

Comment: Yes, @Martin R.

Comment: It is the ordinary measure @Conrad as I have added. And as Martin said, the integrand is the square of the spherical derivative, so $\alpha z+\beta$ will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define on $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ the measure $d\mu:=\frac{1}{(1+|z|^2)^2}dA$, where $dA$ is the usual area measure. It is easy to see that $\mu$ is a finite measure. Now let $\Omega, \Omega_1$ be open sets and let $f:\Omega \to \Omega_1$ be a conformal map. It follows from the change of variable formula that
$$\int_\Omega \frac{|f'|^2}{(1+|f|^2)^2}dA=\int_{f(\Omega)}d\mu$$
More generally, by the Banach indicatrix theorem we have
$$\int_\Omega \frac{|f'|^2}{(1+|f|^2)^2} dA=\int_{f(\Omega)} n(w)d\mu(z)$$
where $n(w):=\#\{z\in \Omega:f(z)=w\}$. If $\infty$ is an essential singularity and $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$, $n(w)=\infty$ for almost every $w\in \mathbb{C}$ and the integral diverges. On the other hand, if $f$ is rational then $n(w)$ is bounded and so the integral is  finite since $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to add that the measure you defined is the spherical metric.

Comment: I recently found a paper of Robert Bryant ”surface of mean curvature one on hyperbolic space”, of which the proposition 4 may provide a strong respond to my original problem.

Comment: @dilong Apologies for the very late reply. I just stumbled upon my answer and your comments again. One quick thing: Picard's great theorem applied to $\infty$ works if $f$ is an holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$ (while it does not necessarily work if $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$). So in your particular situation the answer applies directly without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt is just so close to the conclusion. If we observe that
$$A(r)=\int_{|z|<r}\frac{|f'(z)|^2}{(1+|f(z)|^2)^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y$$ is the area (w.r.t. the ordinary metric on the unit sphere) of the image of $\{|z|<r\}$ under the map
$f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$. If $\infty$ is an essential singularity, then the image of $\mathbb{C}$ covers $\mathbb{S}^2$ for infinitely many times, which is impossible.

Comment: This is essentially the same as @Pelota 's proof. I was inspired by the answer to another question considering the spherical derivative written by Lasse Rempe.